# Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler, nokogiri

Trying to do a `bundle install` to a ruby (sinatra) project and I keep getting this error:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I go ahead and `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` and end with success.

Then I try `bundle install` again and  get the error. Rinse and repeat.

I'm not a ruby dev so I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any help?

Comment: Run `ruby -v`, what do you get back?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

Comment: Do you have a .rvmrc file there?  Also delete the .bundle directory

Comment: I have neither of those, should I?

Comment: A dot file is usually created by a user. It is unlikely you will have one if you have set up the rails project yourself. If it's a team project and you've also got other projects then one of the problems I can envisage is that you have Gem X and Gem Y which could be causing the problem. Hence the suggestion Michael asks about if a .rvmrc is there. The . before the rvmrc means this is a dot file (invisible) ls -la will bring it up.

Comment: Post your `Gemfile` so we can re-create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Bundle update`?

Also, highly recommend you use version control for Ruby - rvm is a great solution. https://rvm.io/

Then you can do `rvm use ruby-version@myNewApp --create`, then ditch --create everytime you use it or use .rvmrc and stick that line in there so it'll auto use nice clean versions of different gems depending for each app you create.

Comment: Did you try using rvm? It will give you a clean gemset and I feel 90% sure will solve your problem and also future problems.

Comment: rvm use 1.9.3 --default cured the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You may check for a ruby version declaration in your Gemfile, maybe it's locked on 1.8